# Why is my android app covered in primaryColor

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I am trying to implement NavigationDrawer.
This code works find but the whole screen is covered in blue which I guess is the primaryColor. I have set the height of the toolbar to `?attr/actionBarSize` I don't know if it's the toolbar or some other object that is causing this. Please explain the cause of the error so I can avoid it in future.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"/>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**toolbar**.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**styles**.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Just noticed, the Toolbar title is also in the middle of the activity. So it must be the toolbar. But I have set the size of the toolbar to ActionBarSize. Those answering, please also explain the reasons. 
[Screen shot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUJoE.png)

**Just in case if you guys need MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

```
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, my_toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can we have screen shot of your activity?

Comment: What does it look like without the NavigationView?

Comment: @KevalPatel Just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Your Xml**

> You show the direct toolbar... so the result take the toolbar as a full content view.. So you should be take the Layout for the mobile content view and inside it you take what you use the toolbar shown in status bar and under below you use your frame or others..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"/>
</LinearLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Answers with just code are not considered good. Please explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: You should be take this because for showing the Content View.....Layout where content is shown...... So these is take Under this if u take this shown there Mobile View and drawer hide in left..

Comment: @Er.Arjun saini This fixed the problem, but I would like to know what caused it.